# How can I set a number of bookings that are allowed by beek

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

How can I set a number of bookings that are allowed by beek, I have a model to define the number of bookings by weeks and months, I am working on C# MVC

I am creating a user vacation booking with C# MVC and I have a model to set number of booking per weeks, I need to know how can I validate that the number of booking is set to the limit amount if it reaches the limit for example 4 it shows a message "only 4 bookings allowed"

I am not sure how to manage weeks on a full calendar

Comment: Please show your effort. The question as currently posed is not accepted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example

Comment: What is "beek"? I mean, besides the name of [the most awesome actor evar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Van_Der_Beek)...

Comment: "beek". Did you mean "week", perhaps? Anyway the simple answer to your question "how can I validate that the number of booking is set to the limit amount" is...ask the database how many bookings are already confirmed for the chosen time period. Or, if the limit is always exactly 4, you can hard-code that into the fullCalendar code (but you had better also check it server-side when saving the booking, because people can find ways round that).

Comment: In terms of making fullCalendar enforce that, then assuming you are allowing users to make choices using the "select" callback, which is the recommended way, then you could check the validity during that callback (because you have access to the chosen dates, and also you can use [getEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents) to find out what events already exist in the calendar (and you can filter them by date to the correct week) and then count them. Or you could just wait until the user actually tries to save the booking and then check. Up to you.